# Is it possible to download an image file using the dryscape Python module?

Tags: python, image, dryscrape

I am trying to use dryscrape to scrape a web page, but is possible to save a particular image from page? It is a normal <img> tag.

Comment: Improved the English of the page and made the question more specific.

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the documentation at https://dryscrape.readthedocs.io/, it does not look like dryscrape supports downloading files. You will have to use a module such as [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can download image with Dryscrape like that

```
img_url = sess.xpath("//img")[0]['href']
sess.visit(img_url)
sess.render("image.png")
```

Try this